# PHP 5.6 Stringed Array to variable Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this string

```
$str = '[{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null}]'
```

And I would like to make it a variable array.

I've searched on net about situations like this but didn't find anything.
Only simple strings like `'some,test,string'` etc.

Any idea how can i approach this?

Comment: The string is a [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Decode it using [`json_decode($str, TRUE);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: what is final code you are expecting output, can you sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use json_decode()  function which convert your string array again

Comment: sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

This string is json encoded object. Use json_decode to parse this string as JSON object. After that you can iterate in loop and print all objects/arrays:

```
$str = '[{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null},{"parousia":null,"proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":null}]';
$json = json_decode($str);

foreach($json as $obj) {
    var_dump((array)$obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'[{"parousia":"krishnsa","proforikos":null,"test":null,"ergasias":null,"telikos":n`ull]}`',

```
$output = json_decode($str, true);
echo $output[0]["parousia"];
```